# How to make a barcode of a very small width?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, barcode, fastreport

I'm trying to create a barcode using Fast-Report. The barcode must be small width like 1.3 cm maximum. But in the Fast-Report there is no way to keep width fixed size. I know it's depending on the string itself but the barcode is for jewelry shop and they are using very small labels for the barcode.

Comment: You should always **add** the generic [tag:delphi] tag to your delphi related questions to have the correct syntax highlighter and more attention on your question.

Comment: Which barcode type you are using? EAN8, 2of5i, ...?

Comment: Find the right size, and pad your strings accordingly?

Comment: @SirRufo I'm using bcCode128A

Comment: You need to work with the zoom property of the barcode object. Set it to a value between 0 and 1 that fits your needs.